# How to replace HDD with an SSD

Tags: ssd

I have been using 3.5 inch 500 GB HDDs & have never used an SSD.

I clone my 500 GB HDD every night using Acronis software so I have a spare HDD in case something goes wrong.

Now I want to buy Western Digital Blue 500 GB SSD.

My question is would I be able to clone it just like regular HDD ? Meaning I will have to make this new SSD as a slave drive & clone it from my HDD so I will have a new bootable SDD with OS & data from old HDD ?

Thank You

Comment: You need a carrier for your SSD and then you should be able to put the clone on it. Watch for different drivers. It may be easier in the long run to put a new system on the SSD and do it that way.

Comment: Are you planning to keep cloning to the SSD, or are you planning to swap them and use the SSD as your main system disk (cloning to the HDD)?

Comment: There are any number of hard disk cloning tools that can and do work. Macrium Reflect, Clonezilla, Acronis are all programs that can clone one disk to another. I've used Macrium several times in the past with no issue.

Comment: @Mokubai Post mentions they already use Acronis. They already have the tools.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but cloning your entire drive every night (to I assume the same second drive) seems like 1. overkill (DEFINITELY don't do this to an SSD) and 2. won't help you with data corruption, or if the primary drive fails while you're overwriting the second one. I would consider cloning bi-annually at most, and rely on an rsync like backup system that keeps versions for your files.

Comment: @MiG it has its pro's and cons. Although I completely understand your point of view, the benefit of a daily clone would be that if the disk dies and the clone had not been made yet, or a config error screws things up, you can get up and running really fast by just swapping the disk, and sort out problems later. If a system must be operational after failure within 15 minutes, this is actually a good approach.

Comment: True, I suppose it depends on if the topic starter refers to a home or corporate environment. In both cases I still hope this is not their exclusive means of making (data) backups though :)

Comment: After clonning, I will use SSD as main drive & HDDs as clones. I am a home user & Clonning has been working. But for some reason in last two days when I tried to delete the partitions of slave drive, using disk management, it won't let me delete one middle partition with data & now those two drives won't detect at all. So is there a solution for those two drives ? Also do I need to install drivers for new SSD before or after clonning or Windows will automatically do it ?

Comment: All my HDDs are "MBR" 
Should I choose "MBR" for SSD too or "GPT" ?

Comment: My suggestion would be Transcend or Apacer. WD is not really good.

Comment: @Mike: Although GPT would be preferred for new installations, when cloning you should select whatever the original disk uses. (Afterwards you could use Windows own mbr2gpt conversion tool if you want.) The disk itself doesn't care either way – MBR/GPT is entirely a software matter.

Comment: After seeing some reviews, I am tempted to go for Samsung 870 EVO. Expensive but since I am going to use it as a Primary, I thought I get something reliable. I also decided to go for clean install & for that I have kept one 500GB HDD with Win-7 & settings done with all updates till 2020. I am using Win-7 due to my GPUs & they are old. So soon I am getting a new system.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you're replacing a SATA HDD with a SATA SSD – yes, it will function exactly the same way, so you can do a 1:1 copy of the original disk. (Assuming it's large enough, as disks sold as "500 GB" can vary a few MB here and there. Acronis will probably take care of that though.)

Answer (score 0):

> I clone my 500 GB HDD every night using Acronis software so I have a
> spare HDD in case something goes wrong.

That's a good thing. Most have a high risk of going disable in 2-3 years if not used carefully.

> My question is would I be able to clone it just like regular HDD ?
> Meaning I will have to make this new SSD as a slave drive & clone it
> from my HDD so I will have a new bootable SDD with OS & data from old
> HDD ?

Cloning is possible. But you have to make sure they are same in size. Or you may have to resize it using softwares like Gparted.